# CTRL+ U in matlab simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink, simulink-library

The open in new tab option does not appear in the context menu as shown below. I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> but it doesn't open either.

[image: Subsystem]

[image: current context menu]

[image: expected context menu]

There is this option in the other 3 dof subsystems, but this option does not appear in the 3 dof subsystem. I need the 'transform to Earth Axes' tab inside.

Comment: CTRL+U is a shortcut for the context menu item  "Mask" > "Look Under Mask", you've not shown the Mask submenu in your screenshots, is the "Look Under Mask" item greyed out within there?